# How to integrate $\int x'(t)\ dx(t)$ and similar?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I just wanted to ask how to integrate the one in the title and also another one which is very similar. Also, I don't know why but *WolframAlpha* just treats the derivatives as contants.

Integrals:
$$\int x'(t) dx(t)\ ;$$
$$\int x'(t)^2 dx(t)\ .$$

I don't really know but using $x'(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}(t)$ and isolating differentials may help.

Comment: I don't think there's a systematic method for evaluating integrals of this form. WolframAlpha treats the derivatives as constants because, to my knowledge, it doesn't know how to deal with Riemann-Stieltjes integrals.

Comment: If $x(t)=\log\log t$, then $$\int x'(t) \, \mathrm{d}x(t) = \int (x'(t))^2 \, \mathrm{d}t = \int \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t^2 \log^2 t} = -\frac{1}{t\log t} - \operatorname{Ei}(-\log t) + \mathsf{C} $$ is not an elementary function. Since any order of derivative of $x(t)$ is elementary, there is no way you can express this integral as a finite combination of derivatives of $x(t)$. The upshot of this observation is that there is in general no way of expressing $\int x'(t) \, \mathrm{d}x(t)$ as an elementary expression of $x(t), x'(t), \ldots$

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a closer look at the first integral as you have suggested. Note it is
$$\int \frac{dx}{dt} d x(t)$$
By the chain rule $dx(t) = x'(t)dt = \frac{dx}{dt} dt$
So the integral is
$$I =\int (\frac{dx}{dt})^2 dt $$
This is perhaps a helpful form.
For the second integral, I think you will find this integration by parts formula for the Riemann-Stieltjes integral helpful in finding a simpler form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I'll look further into these.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong:

$$\frac{d}{dt}x'(t)x(t)=x''(t)x(t)+x'(t)^2$$
$$x'(t)x(t) + C = \int x''(t)x(t) dt+\int x'(t)^2 dt$$
$$\int x'(t)^2 dt = x'(t)x(t) + C - \int x''(t)x(t) dt$$

I can't get further than this...

Comment: The same for second:

$$\int x'(t)^3\ dt = x'(t)^2x+C-\int 2x''(t)x'(t)x(t)\ dt$$